Change the keyboard layout non-interactively
I'm trying to change the keyboard layout to French from a post-install script :
I tried this dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration command but it is interactive.
I don't know how to pass arguments to this command either.
I also tried this :
# localectl set-keymap fr
Setting X11 and console keymaps is not supported in Debian.
#

How can I change the keyboard layout to French non-interactively ?

For the GUI? For the terminal? For both?

@kos First for the terminal. If possible for both :)
